# Microsoft Test Manager initial test suite state 'In Progress'?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

Why is the initial state of a test suite 'In Progress' then you flip it to 'In Planning' then back to 'In progress'? This doesn't make sense to me and I can't find any documentation regarding MTM 2013 states on why this was done? I don't want to edit the states if I don't have to but would like some justification to keep it as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the **state** of a test suite to **indicate whether you are ready to run its tests or whether its tests have all completed.**

If you don't want to use this feature, leave the state at its **default value** of `In Progress`.

> Set the state to inform other team members:
>
> - **In Planning:** The test cases in the suite are not yet ready to run.
> - **In Progress:** The test suite can be run.
> - **Completed:** The tests have completed and do not have to be re-run in    this test suite. You might still run the same test cases
>     in other    test suites or test plans.

***Note:*** The tests in a test suite cannot be run unless its state is **In Progress**.

According to your description, seems you are lacking of the permission  "**Manage Test Suite**" . Then you could not be able to change the state. You could double check this with your TFS Admin. More details please see this link: [Test Suite Security Permissions in MTM](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3627141-test-suite-security-permissions-in-mtm)

---

**Update**

In MTM2010, the default state for a test suite in a test plan is still `In planning`. It's hard to judge a specific period of a product. At that time , one of the top feature requests from Microsoft Test Manager/Test Case Management users across various forums has been the ability to customize the Test Plan and Test Suite artifacts. Based on the feedback, with **Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 3**, we are adding the functionality to add custom fields and workflows to Test Plans and Test Suites.

With TFS 2013 Update 3, you can customize test suite states, and **removed the restriction** to only let you run tests if the test suite state is “In Progress”. Some users like you might have their own custom states that they want to use for tests that can be run, so this change allows more flexibility.

Prior to TFS 2013 Update 3, test plans could only have “Active” and “Inactive” states and test suites could only have “In Planning”, “In Progress”, and “Completed” states. With Update 3, a test plan can be customized to have different workflow states. If you use an MTM client with a version of Visual Studio **prior to Visual Studio 2013 Update 3**, you might get an error when you try to update the state because this version of the client was not designed for custom states. Upgrade your MTM client to Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and you will be able to change the states. Or you can open the test plan or test suite work item directly from MTM (type Ctrl+g, then enter the id of the work item).
More details please refer this blog: [Test Plan and Test Suite Customization with TFS2013 Update3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/05/23/test-plan-and-test-suite-customization-with-tfs2013-update3/)

So in your scenario, the **best solution** is **updating** your **TFS to TFS2013 *update3*** or above and also **updating** VS to **VS2013 *update3*** or above.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My question was more regarding as to why "In Progress" is the initial state after creating a test suite? I don't understand why you would be ready to start testing when no other test cases have been made. Even if you were to query test cases or add requirements there's still a need for review before saying "go ahead and test". Wouldn't it make more sense to have "In planning" as the first state? I have edited our transitions to reflect this change but was curious as to why I had to in the first place. More worried if I was missing something or the reasoning?

Comment: It's the same for test plans... Why would it be active as soon as it was created... No test suites or test cases exist yet. Initial state should be "Inactive" for test plan.

Comment: I must to say in MTM2010, the default state for a test suite in a test plan is *In planning*.  It's hard to judge a specific period of a product.  At that time , one of the top feature requests from Microsoft Test Manager/Test Case Management users across various forums has been the ability to customize the Test Plan and Test Suite artifacts. Based on the feedback, with **Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 3**, we are adding the functionality to add custom fields and workflows to Test Plans and Test Suites.

Comment: With TFS 2013 Update 3, you can customize test suite states, and removed the restriction to only let you run tests if the test suite state is “In Progress”. Some users like you might have their own custom states that they want to use for tests that can be run, so this change allows more flexibility.

Comment: Prior to TFS 2013 Update 3, test plans could only have “Active” and “Inactive” states and test suites could only have “In Planning”, “In Progress”, and “Completed” states. With Update 3, a test plan can be customized to have different workflow states. If you use an MTM client with a version of Visual Studio prior to Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, you might get an error when you try to update the state because this version of the client was not designed for custom states. Upgrade your MTM client to Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and you will be able to change the states. Details see my update answer

Comment: One last question. I can edit my states but my meta states do not map nicely with my new states. Example: my initial state is "In Planning" for my test suite. However when I map these new values in my process configuration and import the new work flow (ex: <state type="InPlanning" value="In Planning" />) I am given errors that my initial state type must be "Inprogress". I am able to change the state values but not how the tool behaves regarding workflow via the meta states. Is this something I should be worried about? Thanks for your responses